# Error when running a crm in php: Module name is missing or incorrect. Please check the module name

Tags: crm, vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger, vticker

After migrating a CRM based on PHP, Mysql and APACHE, it gives the following error: "Module name is missing or incorrect. Please check the module name".This is the CRM called corebosCRM, evolved from Vtiger

I have reinstalled and changed the database 4 times and the same error persists